# Trick: Image inside text which is then used as a div background?

Tags: css

I'm hoping for some CSS help with this one. I'm having trouble combining two CSS concepts:

Using text instead of a background image for a div, but the text used as that background contains an image (i.e.. background-clip: text, etc).

**To re-phrase:**

Creating a text with an image inside it is fairly simple and common (though I wouldn't mind confirming the best syntax for that).

But then I want to take that trick, and set it as the background of a div. That's it. Inside the div, I'll then just have regular text and also a transparent PNG image.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

Basically, I'll end up with a PNG in the foreground (i.e.. div content), with words (i.e.. text) behind it as a background. But those background words should themselves be filled with an image (for texture/aesthetics, etc).

I've tried a few things with no success - it was just a mess, so it probably wouldn't help to post it here.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe (used gradient but you can replace with PNG images)

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, blue, pink, green);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box::before {
  content: "Some text here";
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(yellow, lightblue, orange);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: thanks! Works like a charm. Clean solution too. Are there likely to be any issues with main modern browsers that I should prefix for, or use fallbacks for?

Comment: @Jason849 not really, this should work in all modern browsers. The only thing that may not work is background-clip and in this case it will fallback automatically to a classic background

Comment: @Temani_Afif OK. I've been working with it - all is good. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hey just wondering, is there any way to add something like `animation: type 5s steps(11, end);}` to the background text? Thanks again.